# fourier transform for $H_s$ function

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I am looking for a result that I think is a standard in sobolev spaces, here is the question:

for $ 1\le p \le2$ and $g\in H_s (R^n)$ for $ s>n(1/p-1/2)$ I want to prove thst $g$ is a Fourier transform for a function in $L^p (R^n)$

$H_s$ is a sobolev space.

I do think this is a standard result, but I couldn`t find it. Any help please

Comment: If I remember correctly, Fourier transform can be seen as a map $F:L^p\to L^q$ for $1\le p \le 2$, $q= \frac{p}{p-1}$. Maybe a Sobolev inclusion will help here.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $ H_s  \subset L^p \rightarrow  L^p $  so the condition on s comes from  $ 1 \le p \le 2 $ ?

Comment: You already have this condition, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Fourier inversion you have that $g = \mathscr{F} \mathscr{F}^{-1} g$. By assumption you have $g \in H_s$ so that $$\int |\mathscr{F}^{-1}g(\xi)|^2 (1 + |\xi|^2)^{s} \mathrm{d} \xi < \infty.$$

Observe that this implies $f := \mathscr{F}^{-1} g \in L^p$, for 
$$ \int |f(\xi)|^p \mathrm{d}\xi = \int |f(\xi)|^p \frac{(1 + |\xi|^2)^{sp/2}}{(1 + |\xi|^2)^{sp/2}} \mathrm{d}\xi $$
and hence by Holder's inequality you get
$$ \leq \left(\int |f(\xi)|^2 (1 + |\xi|^2)^s \mathrm{d}\xi\right)^{p/2} \cdot \left( \int (1 + |\xi|^2)^{sp/(2-p)} \mathrm{d}\xi \right)^{1 - p/2}.$$
To conclude, by assumption you have that $2sp/(2-p) > n$ and hence $(1 + |\xi|^2)^{sp/(2-p)}$ is integrable, so $f$ is indeed in $L^p$.